# iPad storyBoard not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, storyboard

I started out with the Master-Detail application in XCode 4.2.

It is my first app using storyboard so I knew I would miss something on the way.

Ok, so I started out my app coding my master controller and my detail controller.

It works nice on the iPhone simulator but I cannot get it to work on the iPad simulator and I dont know why. Cuz the only thing that appears to me on the log is (gdb) and it shows me the following line on AppDelegate.h:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

I know I missed the part of testing on the iPad simulator from the beginning, but is there a way to know what is going on precisely?

Comment: Can you post some code, and, if possible, a screenshot of your Xcode error?

Comment: I started out removing some code to see what was going on. I realized that since the iPad storyBoard also loads the detail view, it was "crashing" because I didn't have the detail data loaded. But no erros would appear...

Comment: So have you solved it? If so, just put an answer to your question so any future readers know the solution

Comment: Well its not an answer for every problem like this... it was specific, but I will write something as an answer then.

Comment: It might be a specific issue, but it's good SO practice to answer your own question if you figure it out for yourself :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started out removing some code to see what was going on. I realized that since the iPad storyBoard also loads the detail view, it was "crashing" because I didn't have the detail data loaded. But no erros would appear...

So I just added a code to verify if the detail view had any details ready to show.

```
if (self.detailDict) {
    // do something with the data
}
```

After that I started working around. And this code does not interfere on the iPhone since the detailDict would be properly passed when the table cell is tapped.